# Better Window Management Mathematica

Tags: windows-7, mathematica

In versions of Mathematica in Linux all new notebooks appeared as separate windows.

In Mathematica 9 for Windows 7, I have only 1 window in the taskbar now, and when I minimize notebooks they minimize into the bottom left corner.

I really enjoyed being able to glance down at my taskbar to see all windows currently open.

**How do you have each notebook represent a new task in the taskbar?**

I believe it might require combining the textbar at the top with with each notebook.

Alternatively, does anyone have any techniques for better window management in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"better window management in Windows" sounds awesome. Anyway, not sure it's exactly what you're looking for, but if you right-click on the taskbar and hit Properties -> Taskbar buttons -> Combine only if screen is full, you can disable the Windows 7 combining behavior entirely. That makes it a lot more like Windows XP and a lot of Linux distros.

Comment: Unfortunately Mathematica doesn't seem to respect that setting.  No matter what setting I set under the taskbar Mathematica combines the windows into one task in the taskbar.